# Duda consulta XQuery

Tags: xml

Buenos días tengo problemas con un consulta en xquery.

Mi xml tiene la siguiente estructura (pongo solo un nodo como ejemplo):

```
<produc>
  <cod_prod>1022</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Placa Base ASRock G41M-S3 </denominacion>
    <precio>52</precio>
    <stock_actual>2</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>2</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>30</cod_zona>
  </produc>
</productos>
```

A partir de ahí quiero listar los productos cuyo stock actual sea menor al mínimo, pero la query siempre me devuelve todos los productos.
Esta es la query que estoy usando

```
for $values in collection('peval5acda')//productos/produc
where stock_actual < stock_minimo
return $values
```

Answer (score 0):

Establecer contexto.

Posibles opciones con el mismo resultado:

1)

```
for $values in collection('peval5acda')//productos/produc
where $values[ stock_actual < stock_minimo ]
return $values
```

2)

```
for $values in collection('peval5acda')//productos/produc[ stock_actual < stock_minimo ]
return $values
```

3)

```
collection('peval5acda')//productos/produc[ stock_actual < stock_minimo ]
```